# Ruby one line of code, interrupting a block

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write one line of code to tell me if there is an element in an array that meets a set of criteria and then breaks on true.

For example

I have `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` and I want to find the first element that is divisible by 2 and 3. I want to write a one liner that will return true as soon as it hits 6 and not process the remaining elements in the array.

I can write a for each loop and break, but I feel like there should be a way to do that in one line of code.

Comment: If it is divisible by both 3 and 2, then it is divisible by 6. Use #find or #any depending on what you want to know (the same block will work) `[...].find { |n| n % 6 == 0 }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].any?{|e| e % 2 == 0 && e % 3 == 0}
```

or you can combine it with [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) and have a great tutorial example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].any?{|e| [2, 3].all?{|d| e % d == 0}}
```

And if you actually need the first matching element returned, use `find`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].find{|e| [2,3].all?{|d| e % d == 0}}
# => 6
```

Comment: any? doesn't return the value, it only checks if there is such a value

Comment: `any?` _returns_ a boolean value, which actually answers OP's question: _if there is an element in an array that meets a set of criteria_.

Answer (score 4):

You should use: find

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].find{|e| e % 2 == 0 && e % 3 == 0}
```

It will return 6, and it won't process the values after 6.